# ERROR missing EOF at 'select'

Tags: sql, select, syntax-error, eof

Why do I get this error? I'm trying to do queries and for this i need of several selects from different tables, without any combination, but I'm getting this error and I don't known why.

Syntax error(s) [missing EOF at 'select']

Code:

```
select 
d.tdok typ,
d.nr numer,
d.symbmg symbol,
d.data dataDok,
d.dokumwe dokumWe,
d.datawe datawe,
d.idkntrh idKth,
d.kwotadok kwotadok,
d.kwotavat,
k.nazwa1 nazwa1,
k.nazwa2 nazwa2
from dokum0 d
join kontrahent0 k on d.idkntrh=k.idkntrh
select t.kwota_n kwota_n 
    from dokumterm t 
    where t.dokum_id = id_dokum;
select p.id_pozdok0 AS settledCount
    from pozdok p   
    where p.dokum_id = id_dokum;
select p.id_pozdok0 AS posCount 
    from pozdok p 
    where p.dokum_id=id_dokum;
select t.kupspr kupspr  
    from sltdok t 
    where t.tdok=tdok;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You dont have semicolon (;) after end of first select... So this:

```
join kontrahent0 k on d.idkntrh=k.idkntrh
```

should be:

```
join kontrahent0 k on d.idkntrh=k.idkntrh;
```